# I want to query result with specific year ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to query a result with specific year ranges. For example result with the year 5 to 10 .

```
select * from Employee
where dateHired >= 5 and dateHired <= 10
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your current query?

Comment: is this the right way to do? cuz it couldnt be executed.

Comment: dateHired >= sysdate – interval ‘5’ year and dateHired <= sysdate – interval ‘10’ year, idk if this is possible in oracle?

Comment: bcuz my data within the table is in date format

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but one of the simplest is this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employees e
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(e.dateHired, SYSDATE) BETWEEN 60 AND 120;
```

Comment: what if the data displayed must be always in a range of 5 - 10 years?

Comment: may i know what is the 60 and 120 represents?

Comment: @JoshuaTabi There are 12 months in a year.  5 (years) * 12 (months) = 60.  10 (years) * 12 (months) = 120

Answer (score 0):

To find dates e.g. between 2005 and 2010, you may use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE dateHired >= date '2005-01-01' AND dateHired < date '2011-01-01';
```

Comment: if the date is in dd-mm-yyyy, should i do it like this WHERE dateHired >= date 01-01-2005' AND dateHired < date '01-01-2010'; ?

Comment: Are you storing your dates as _text_?  If so, then stop doing that.

Comment: Don't confuse text and date literals. Date literals have a fixed ANSI format YYYY-MM-DD, which does not depend on the NLS-settings.

Answer (score 0):

I like Del's solution, but it will not use the index for the dateHired column, if it exists. I suggest a variant of the solution, which will do INDEX RANGE SCAN.

```
SELECT *
FROM employees e
WHERE e.dateHired BETWEEN add_months(SYSDATE, -12 * 10) and add_months(SYSDATE, -12 * 5) ;
```

Comment: This will fail on `2024-02-29`. Don't subtract `INTERVAL '1' YEAR` , use `ADD_MONTHS`.

Comment: Thank you for the very important clarification. I corrected the error.